# Displaying finder directory path in unix format on mac os x yosemite

Tags: macos, finder, osx-yosemite

Apple is sometimes professional in making simple things extremely complicated...

All I'm trying to do is to copy a large directory path from finder into the terminal. But I can't find it in unix format. If I right click a file/folder and go to information, the 'place' is described with arrows e.g. primair ▸ private ▸ tmp rather than /primair/private/tmp. Does someone know how I can make finder display the path in good old unix format? Or an alternative to quickly copy a directory path on finder in unix format?

Obviously the path I want to copy is much larger.

Comment: Does dragging the folder from Finder to Terminal get you what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging the file or folder into terminal gives you the path in unix form